# How does "very much" fit in with "thank you very much"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

I would never say, "I am sorry very much" or "You're welcome very much", why is it that it fits well with "Thank You"?

Comment: Someone please tell [Jimmy Valmer](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Jimmy_Valmer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Thank you very much** could be regarded as a short form of "*I thank you very much*", which is entirely sensible.

On the other hand, you might say "I am very sorry".

Answer (score 6):

A possible reasoning is this: *sorry* and *welcome* here are adjectives, while *thank you* is an exclamation. You can add the adverb *very* in front of sorry and welcome to say

> I am very sorry.
>
> You are very welcome.